# Generate RESTful Proxy from WSDL

Tags: java, php, web-services, rest, wsdl

Let's say I was given WSDLs for some web services. I really need RESTful services as I will be creating a JavaScript client.

Is there any tool to create RESTful services that act as a proxy to the traditional web services?

I don't care what language...PHP, Java...whatever.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know of a tool, but I'll just put out the thought that this may not exist simply because the conversion from a general WSDL to a REST service isn't a clear mapping.  WSDL is very general and encompasses things like SOAP which are (religious wars aside) more expressive. That said, there might be a subset of WSDL that could be mapped to REST and one could feasibly write a restful webservice using a WSDL

Comment: But, but, but....I just want to hit a button, and voila! Yea, I'm not too familiar with the WSDL format, so that may very well be the case.

Comment: You can access SOAP services from javascript as well as RESTfull services, can't you?

Comment: @Stas - sure you can, but I think the OP is looking for some sort of code generation tool that will proxy (as in the design pattern or the server) requests to a service from an equivalent REST interface via the old WSDL based one.

Comment: @spinning_plate, for me, it looks like OP is looking for such tool because he don't understand possibility of javascript - SOAP communication.

Comment: @Stas - you might be right, I'll let him answer.

Comment: @Stas - You are right. I always consume via RESTful services, so I am not familiar with JS-SOAP communication. However, I highly doubt it will be as straightforward and lean on the client side. I will have to look into this.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a ready made solution that can fit this need.

However, you might cook something together.

With the use of [WSDL 2.0](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restwsdl/) you can define a REST based webservice. [A sample WSDL defining a REST service](http://dev.w3.org/cvsweb/2002/ws/desc/test-suite/documents/good/HTTPBinding-1G/Echo.wsdl?rev=1.3)

With use of [Woden](http://ws.apache.org/woden/) or [W3C WSDL Converter](http://www.w3.org/2006/02/WSDLConvert.html) - you can convert a WSDL 1.1 document to a WSDL 2.0.

However, even after doing all of this - you would need a translator (kind of an ESB pattern) to translate these REST calls to SOAP based.

My 2 cents - An ideal solution would involve writing the middleware logic (probably on an ESB) - exposing the service as REST based while the provider is still traditional.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Nishant that an ESB could do the job. For example have a look at [Mule](http://www.mulesoft.org/). [Here](http://forums.mulesoft.org/thread.jspa?threadID=4498) there is a forum discussion that might interest you.